# Flatten rows in sliding window using Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm processing a large number of rows from either a database or a file using Apache Spark. Part of the processing creates a sliding window of 3 rows where the rows need to flattened and additional calculations performed on the flattened rows. Below is a simplified example of what is trying to be done.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

object Main extends App {

  val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("DataSet Test")
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import ss.implicits._

  case class Foo(a:Int, b:String )

  // rows from database or file
  val foos = Seq(Foo(-18, "Z"),
      Foo(-11, "G"),
      Foo(-8, "A"),
      Foo(-4, "C"),
      Foo(-1, "F")).toDS()

  // work on 3 rows
  val sliding_window_spec = Window.orderBy(desc("a")).rowsBetween( -2, 0)

  // flattened object with example computations
  case class FooResult(a1:Int, b1:String, a2:Int, b2:String, a3:Int, b3:String, computation1:Int, computation2:String  )

  // how to convert foo to fooResult???
  // flatten 3 rows into 1 and do additional computations on flattened rows

  // expected results
  val fooResults = Seq(FooResult( -1, "F", -4, "C", -8, "A", -5, "FCA" ),
    FooResult( -4, "C", -8, "A", -11, "G", -12, "CAG" ),
    FooResult( -8, "A", -11, "G", -18, "Z", -19, "AGZ" )).toDS()

   ss.stop()

}
```

How can I convert the foos into the fooResults? I'm using Apache Spark 2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `// how to convert foo to fooResult???
>   // flatten 3 rows into 1 and do additional computations on flattened rows`

You can simply use `collect_list` *inbuilt function* using the `window` function *you've already defined* and then by defining a `udf` function, you can *do the computation part and flattening part*. finally you can `filter` and *expand the `struct` column to get your final desired result* as

```
def slidingUdf = udf((list1: Seq[Int], list2:Seq[String])=> {
  if(list1.size < 3) null
  else {
    val zipped = list1.zip(list2)
    FooResult(zipped(0)._1, zipped(0)._2, zipped(1)._1, zipped(1)._2, zipped(2)._1, zipped(2)._2, zipped(0)._1+zipped(1)._1, zipped(0)._2+zipped(1)._2+zipped(2)._2)
  }
})

foos.select(slidingUdf(collect_list("a").over(sliding_window_spec), collect_list("b").over(sliding_window_spec)).as("test"))
    .filter(col("test").isNotNull)
    .select(col("test.*"))
    .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+
|a1 |b1 |a2 |b2 |a3 |b3 |computation1|computation2|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+
|-1 |F  |-4 |C  |-8 |A  |-5          |FCA         |
|-4 |C  |-8 |A  |-11|G  |-12         |CAG         |
|-8 |A  |-11|G  |-18|Z  |-19         |AGZ         |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+
```

**Note: Remember that the case classes should be defined outside the scope of the current session**

Comment: Thanks this works. Given I may have many columns to work with is there a way to pass in the Foo object into the udf function, rather than breaking the object into separate lists? I can't work out a way to pass the whole object in from the foos.select statement so using something other than collect_list.

Comment: If it works and helped you get ideas on how to proceed to your next step, you should consider accepting and upvoting it @MarkSivill and for the other context you've mentioned, a detailed next question would get an answer for sure. if not me somebody else would