# Pass row/object from sliding window into UDF with Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to process an row/object with many columns as part of a sliding window using a custom UDF. Individual columns can be passed to custom UDF using collect_list but given there is large number of columns I would prefer to pass the row/object directly to make management of the code easier (as columns will be added/removed and not all columns will always be required for processing ). Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Foo(a:Int, b:String )
case class FooResult(a1:Int, b1:String, a2:Int, b2:String, a3:Int, b3:String, computation1:Int, computation2:String  )

object Main extends App {

    val ss = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("DataSet Test")
        .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import ss.implicits._

    val foos = Seq(Foo(-18, "Z"),
        Foo(-11, "G"),
        Foo(-8, "A"),
        Foo(-4, "C"),
        Foo(-1,"F")).toDS()

    // work on 3 rows
    val sliding_window_spec = Window.orderBy(desc("a")).rowsBetween( -2, 0)

    // ????
    // how to pass in whole object to a custom UDF
    // tried $"root", $""
    // ????
    foos.select(slidingUdf(  $"*".over(sliding_window_spec)).as("test"))
      .filter(col("test").isNotNull)
      .select(col("test.*"))
      .show(false)

    ss.stop()

    def slidingUdf = udf((list1: Seq[Foo] )=> {
                if(list1.size < 3) {
                  null
                }
                else {
                    FooResult(list1(0).a, list1(0).b, list1(1).a, list1(1).b, list1(2).a, list1(2).b, list1(0).a + list1(1).a, list1(0).b + list1(1).b + list1(2).b )
                }
            })

}
```

How can I pass a foo row/object into the UDF? I'm using Apache Spark 2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to achieve the same result of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243232/flatten-rows-in-sliding-window-using-spark). Your logic seems to be perfect but you have committed certain mistakes. So lets start with your mistakes

## Mistake 1

if you define the *dataset* as

```
val foos = Seq(Foo(-18, "Z"),
  Foo(-11, "G"),
  Foo(-8, "A"),
  Foo(-4, "C"),
  Foo(-1,"F")).toDS()
```

You would get *dataset* with *schema* as

```
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|-18|Z  |
|-11|G  |
|-8 |A  |
|-4 |C  |
|-1 |F  |
+---+---+

root
 |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see that *Foo struct object is already separated as different columns* (which is not what you want)

## Mistake 2

You have defined your `udf` function as

```
def slidingUdf = udf((list1: Seq[Foo] )=> {...
```

It is *not possible to use custom datatypes in input arguments of udf functions*. You can just *use sql datatypes* only

## Mistake 3

**`$"*"` doesn't collect all the column values in the range you have defined in window function**. You have to *use a function, either inbuilt function or custom*

*There are other minor mistakes too*.

**Now lets solve the mistakes**

## solved 1

You should define the *dataset* as

```
val foos = Seq(
  (Foo(-18, "Z"), "test"),
  (Foo(-11, "G"), "test"),
  (Foo(-8, "A"), "test"),
  (Foo(-4, "C"), "test"),
  (Foo(-1,"F"), "test"))
  .toDF("foo", "test")
```

which should give you

```
+--------+----+
|foo     |test|
+--------+----+
|[-18, Z]|test|
|[-11, G]|test|
|[-8, A] |test|
|[-4, C] |test|
|[-1, F] |test|
+--------+----+

root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```

Here `test` column is *a dummy column* can be neglected but *was necessary to create dataset*

## solved 2

working `udf` function should be as below

```
def slidingUdf = udf((list1: Seq[Row] )=> {
  if(list1.size < 3) {
    null
  }
  else {
    FooResult(list1(0).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(0).getAs[String]("b"), list1(1).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(1).getAs[String]("b"), list1(2).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(2).getAs[String]("b"), list1(0).getAs[Int]("a") + list1(1).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(0).getAs[String]("b") + list1(1).getAs[String]("b") + list1(2).getAs[String]("b"))
  }
})
```

I have used `Row` as it *is a datatype* for `struct` columns and also look at how data are extracted from a `Row`

## solved 3

you should use `collect_list` *inbuilt function* with `window` function as

```
foos.select(slidingUdf(collect_list("foo").over(sliding_window_spec)).as("test"))
  .filter(col("test").isNotNull)
  .select(col("test.*"))
  .show(false)
```

## So overall working code is

```
val foos = Seq(
  (Foo(-18, "Z"), "test"),
  (Foo(-11, "G"), "test"),
  (Foo(-8, "A"), "test"),
  (Foo(-4, "C"), "test"),
  (Foo(-1,"F"), "test"))
  .toDF("foo", "test")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// work on 3 rows
val sliding_window_spec = Window.orderBy(desc("foo.a")).rowsBetween( -2, 0)

def slidingUdf = udf((list1: Seq[Row] )=> {
  if(list1.size < 3) {
    null
  }
  else {
    FooResult(list1(0).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(0).getAs[String]("b"), list1(1).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(1).getAs[String]("b"), list1(2).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(2).getAs[String]("b"), list1(0).getAs[Int]("a") + list1(1).getAs[Int]("a"), list1(0).getAs[String]("b") + list1(1).getAs[String]("b") + list1(2).getAs[String]("b"))
  }
})

foos.select(slidingUdf(collect_list("foo").over(sliding_window_spec)).as("test"))
  .filter(col("test").isNotNull)
  .select(col("test.*"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+
|a1 |b1 |a2 |b2 |a3 |b3 |computation1|computation2|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+
|-1 |F  |-4 |C  |-8 |A  |-5          |FCA         |
|-4 |C  |-8 |A  |-11|G  |-12         |CAG         |
|-8 |A  |-11|G  |-18|Z  |-19         |AGZ         |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+
```

You can play around for more learning and understanding. I hope the answer is more than helpful ;)

Comment: This did give pointers to come up with what I needed. The crux of the problem is you can't directly pass the whole object into the udf function. The work around I came up with was to create a FooWrapper object and functions then map the Foo object in and out of it. I'll create another answer with the code as there isn't have enough space to add it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I'm using based on [Ramesh Maharjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5880706/ramesh-maharjang) pointers

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,udf,collect_list}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Foo(a:Int, b:String ) {
  def toFooWrapper:FooWrapper = FooWrapper(this,true)
}

// utility class to convert Foo from correctly defined Row
object Foo {
  def fromRow( row:Row ):Foo = {
    Foo(row.getAs[Int]("a"),row.getAs[String]("b"))
  }
}

case class FooWrapper(foo:Foo, wrapper:Boolean)

case class FooResult(a1:Int, b1:String, a2:Int, b2:String, a3:Int, b3:String, computation1:Int, computation2:String )

object Main extends App {

    val ss = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("DataSet Test")
        .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import ss.implicits._

    val foos = Seq(Foo(-18, "Z"),
        Foo(-11, "G"),
        Foo(-8, "A"),
        Foo(-4, "C"),
        Foo(-1,"F")).toDS()

    // workaround - build wrapper
    val fooWrappers = foos.map( x => x.toFooWrapper )

    // work on 3 rows
    // ordering based on first column, second column, etc within Foo structure
    val sliding_window_spec = Window.orderBy(desc("foo")).rowsBetween(-2, 0)

    // grab foo from fooWrapper
  fooWrappers.select(slidingUdf( collect_list("foo").over(sliding_window_spec) ).as("test"))
    .filter(col("test").isNotNull)
    .select(col("test.*"))
    .show(false)

    ss.stop()

    def slidingUdf = udf( (rows:Seq[Row]) => {
        if(rows.size < 3) {
            null
        }
        else {
            val foos = rows.map( x => Foo.fromRow(x))
            FooResult(foos(0).a, foos(0).b, foos(1).a, foos(1).b, foos(2).a, foos(2).b, foos(0).a + foos(1).a, foos(0).b + foos(1).b + foos(2).b )
        }
    })

}
```